# Ayuda con un error al pasarle datos a una IA a traves de partial_fit()

Tags: python, inteligencia-artificial

estoy intentando que una IA juegue recolecte datos y aprenda, todo fumciona correctamente, pero a la hora de pasarle los datos recolectados para que aprenda ma de el siguente error:

> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 2]

Este es el codigo

```
collect_target = []
collect_data = []

while jugar == 0:

    Player = input()
    if Player=="salir":
        jugar = 1
    elif Player=="entrenar":
        train_target=traductor(0,1,x_palabra,x_numero,collect_target)
        train_data=traductor(0,1,y_palabra,y_numero,collect_data)
        print(train_target)
        print(train_data)
        soldado = soldado.partial_fit([train_target],train_data)
    else:
        jugada = soldado.predict_proba([traductor(0,0,x_palabra,x_numero,Player)])[0]
        if jugada[0] >= 0.8:
            IA = action[0]
        elif jugada[1] >= 0.8:
            IA = action[1]
        else:
            IA = azar(action)
        mision = good(Player,IA)
        if mision==0:
            print("Entity: %s Action: %s Mision Cumplida" %(Player,IA))
            score["win"]+=1
            collect_target.append(Player)
            collect_data.append(IA)
        elif mision==1:
            print("Entity: %s Action: %s Mision Fallida" %(Player,IA))
            score["loose"]+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontre la solucion, resulta que el segundo parametro tenia que ingresarlo como matriz
estaba :

> soldado = soldado.partial_fit([train_target],train_data)

Y tenia que ser:

> soldado = soldado.partial_fit([train_target],[train_data])